# How to increase number of terms in an equation based on user input MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, differential-equations

I'm writing MATLAB code which will solve a set of equations simultaneously. However the user will decide how many equations there are.

For example if the user wants to solve 5 equations, each equation shall also have 5 terms - 4 equations = 4 terms in each equation. The image attached to this question shows what I mean

[image: The Equation]

So in MATLAB, how can I code such that if the user let's say enters : 50 as the size. It creates 50 equations with 50 terms in each equation.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is

```
dP_dt = P.*(-alpha+gamma*P);
```

where of course `alpha` and `gamma` have to be vectors of the correct dimension. If necessary, you have to restrict them to the size of `P`

```
dP_dt = P.*(-alpha(1:N,1)+gamma(1:N,1:N)*P);
```